# Memory error while concatenating data frames in Python

Tags: python, csv, docker

I have a large csv file of 680 MB which i have to read inside a dataframe.

I am splitting the file into chunks and then appending those chunks to a list.

Then i am trying to create a consolidated dataframe by using pd.concat().

I am using below code to achieve this:

```
temp_list = []
chunksize = 10 ** 5

for chunk in pd.read_csv('./data/properties_2016.csv', chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False):
  temp_list.append(chunk)

properties_df = temp_list[0]

for df in temp_list[1:]:
   properties_df = pd.concat([properties_df, df], ignore_index=True)
```

I am trying to do this by running a docker image.

I am getting below memory error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dataIngestion.py", line 53, in <module>
properties_df = pd.concat([properties_df, df], ignore_index=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 206, in concat
copy=copy)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 266, in __init__
obj._consolidate(inplace=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3156, in _consolidate
self._consolidate_inplace()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3138, in _consolidate_inplace
self._protect_consolidate(f)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3127, in _protect_consolidate
result = f()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3136, in f
self._data = self._data.consolidate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3573, in consolidate
bm._consolidate_inplace()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3578, in _consolidate_inplace
self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4525, in _consolidate
_can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4548, in _merge_blocks
new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

Please help here!!

Comment: Did you try reading the whole csv without chunking? 680 MB doesn't sound that big to read using pandas' read_csv.

Comment: Yeah i tried that but the process was getting `killed`

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating DataFrames doesn't work this way. I think this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) would be helpful

This is the correct way to do it

```
temp_list = []
chunksize = 10 ** 5

for chunk in pd.read_csv('./data/properties_2016.csv', chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=False):
    temp_list.append(chunk)

frames = []
for df in temp_list:
    frames.append(df)
properties_df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)
```

I tried it on a small file and worked, please let me know if you still have the same error.

Comment: i tried the way suggested by you. Now, instead of getting the above error, i am just getting `Killed`

Comment: i tried increasing my docker memory and it ran successfully!!